# How to drop all the columns except few in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

If there is a table 'Table_Name' I want to drop all the columns in Table_Name except few. I have been able to do that manually by specifying each and every column name but is there any simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this quest can simplify your asking requirement:

```
SET @myquery = (SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE Table_Name ', GROUP_CONCAT(' DROP 
COLUMN ', `COLUMN_NAME`)) 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='DB_NAME' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='Table_Name' AND `COLUMN_NAME` NOT IN ('name', 'password'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Replace DB_NAME, Table_Name and your column list with **'name', 'password'** which you want to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL needs to be explicit with every column you delete. You can drop more than one at once however:

```
ALTER TABLE x
DROP COLUMN one,
DROP COLUMN two,
DROP COLUMN three
```